# Infinite looping when inserting an item into a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, infinite-loop

Trying to insert a value into a linked list, but it enters an infinite loop when it is passed through the 2nd time. Been scratching my head for an hour for this problem. Is it due to variable placement issues or just algorithm in general?

Edit 1: Changed NULL to nullptr, created a counter that tells the value of karak each loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct List {
    char karak;
    List* next = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    List* start = nullptr, * end = nullptr, * list = new List(), * trav = new List();
    int no = 0;
    cout << "Enter Numbers : ";
    cin >> no;
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        trav = start;
        cout << "Enter No. " << (i + 1) << " : ";
        cin >> list->karak;
        if (i == 0) {
            start = list;
            end = list;
        }
        else {
            for (; trav->next != nullptr; trav = trav->next) { // infinite loop
                cout << "\ntest\n";
            }
            trav->next = list;
            end = list;
        }
        cout << "\n\nList Address No. " << (i + 1) << " : " << start->next << "\n\n";
        cout << "\n\nStart : " << start->karak << "\nEnd : " << end->karak << "\n\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: Run your program in the debugger and take note of every variable's value as you enter the `else` branch. Make a drawing with boxes and arrows, that also helps visualize your list structure.

Comment: `trav->next` is never initialized. You must not assume it starts as `nullptr`.

Comment: but trav is initialized as start, does it not follow start -> next?

Comment: @Yrgus `List` doesn't have a constructor that sets `next` equal to `nullptr`, nor is there any in-class initialization of `next`. What exactly are you expecting to initialize `next`?

Comment: `struct List {
    char karak;
    List* next = nullptr;
};` would solve one issue. Also; stop using `NULL` in modern C++. Use `nullptr`.

Comment: @Jesper Implemented your changes and it's still the same infinite loop, is there a difference between NULL and nullptr? Wondering cause I'm used to using NULL

Comment: @Yrgus Yes, there's a difference and `nullptr` is superior in every way. For starters, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr

Comment: First you set `start = nullptr`, then you set `trav = start;`, then you evaluate `trav->next`. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @Beta The first loop initializes the value of start and end so shouldn't trav stores the value of list? Or am I really oblivious about this, sorry about that

Comment: @Beta I understand that the initial value of ```trav``` is ```nullptr```, but it won't enter the ```else```, the next loop will set the ```trav``` to the previous's loop of ```list```.

Comment: **I eat my words. I was completely wrong.** I am short on sleep, but that doesn't excuse such an error.

Comment: You are making things harder on yourself by trying to do everything in `main`. It would be easier if you broke your task into smaller pieces and wrote a function for each piece. (Repeat for even smaller pieces if it helps.) Then test each piece individually to make sure it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object need to be created inside the loop to prevent the list from becoming a circular linked list. So I added list = new List(); inside the loop so the program can create the objects inside the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct List {
    char karak;
    List* next = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    List* start = nullptr, * end = nullptr, * list = new List(), * trav = new List();
    int no = 0;
    cout << "Enter Numbers : ";
    cin >> no;
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        trav = start;
        list = new List();                      \\I added here
        cout << "Enter No. " << (i + 1) << " : ";
        cin >> list->karak;
        if (i == 0) {
            start = list;
            end = list;
        }
        else {
            for (; trav->next != nullptr; trav = trav->next) { 
                cout << "\ntest\n";
            }
            trav->next = list;
            end = list;
        }
        cout << "\n\nList Address No. " << (i + 1) << " : " << start->next << "\n\n";
        cout << "\n\nStart : " << start->karak << "\nEnd : " << end->karak << "\n\n";
    }

}
```